# Redshift - CASE statement checking column EXISTS or no

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am querying dynamically tables where some of the tables might not have specific column. My intention is check the existence of the column and dynamically assign a value. Basically if all the tables would contain the field I would just write simply :

```
select name, count(k_val) from tbl GROUP by 1
```

But in my case I need to do something like this:

```
select name, 
    SUM( (CASE when (select EXISTS( SELECT * FROM pg_table_def WHERE tablename = 'tbl'
                                            and "column" = 'k_val')) 
                then 1 else 0 end) ) as val  
    from tbl GROUP by 1
```

I am getting the error:

> SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: Amazon Invalid operation:
>   Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on
>   Redshift tables.;

Comment: Your sample is equivalent to `COUNT(*)` or `0`.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a trick that works on most databases to handle missing columns.

```
select t.*,
       (select k_val  -- intentionally not qualified
        from tbl t2
        where t2.pk = t.pk
       ) new_k_val
from tbl t cross join
     (select NULL as k_val) k;
```

`pk` is the primary key column for the table.  This uses scoping rules to find a value for `k_val`.  If `k_val` is in the table, then the subquery will use the value from that row.  If not, then the scope will "reach out" and take the value from `k`.  There is no confusion in this case, because `k_val` is not in `tbl`.

If you don't want a constant subquery for some reason, you can always use:

```
     (select NULL as k_val from t limit 1) k
```

You can then use this as a subquery or CTE for your aggregation purposes.

Having said all that, I am wary of handling missing columns this way.

Comment: This is confirmed as WORKING on Redshift (!)